# How to save huge json object in session?

Tags: json, spring, hibernate, session

I am developing an application, where i need to save rows returned from db to page(which is in the form of json) to the session of the user.

I am using jquery on the client-side and springMVC framework + Hibernate for the backend. 
The size of the json returned is approximately 200kb which i need to maintain in user session. What is the best possible way to achieve this?

Comment: Saving this kind of information in Session is pretty discouraged. What are your reasons for wanting to do this? It may make more sense to cache queries in SQL or your database system and only store the query in the session and have your database handle when to cache or release it. And you'll have less I/O operations when user visits the page

Answer (score 0):

You'd better use a cache-server; redis, memcached,infinispan.
I recommend infinispan.
[infinispan url](http://www.jboss.org/infinispan/)